# Python TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, sorting, arguments

I try to write a small class and want to sort the items based on the weight. The code is provided,

```
class Bird:

    def __init__(self, weight):
        # __weight for the private variable
        self.__weight = weight

    def weight(self):
        return self.__weight

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Bird, weight = " + str(self.__weight)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create a list of Bird objects.
    birds = []
    birds.append(Bird(10))
    birds.append(Bird(5))
    birds.append(Bird(200))

    # Sort the birds by their weights.
    birds.sort(lambda b: b.weight())

    # Display sorted birds.
    for b in birds:
        print(b)
```

When I run the program, I get the error stack of `Python TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments`. Whats the issue here?

Comment: This error is specific for python3 actually.  Python2 would assume the function given to sort is a cmp-function.  The code above will still break as you're giving it a key-function.  I found this Q because my python2-script broke when running under python3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exactly what it says: `sort` doesn't take any positional arguments. It takes a keyword-only argument named `key`:

```
birds.sort(key=lambda b: b.weight())
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> sort(*, key=None, reverse=False)
>
> This method sorts the list in place,
>   using only `<` comparisons between items. Exceptions are not suppressed
>   - if any comparison operations fail, the entire sort operation will fail (and the list will likely be left in a partially modified state).
>
> `sort()` accepts two arguments that **can only be passed by keyword**
>   (keyword-only arguments):
>
> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element (for example, `key=str.lower`). The key corresponding to each item in the list is calculated once and then used for the entire sorting process. The default value of `None` means that list items are sorted directly without calculating a separate key value.
>
> [...]

The `*` in the signature is the separator between positional parameters and keyword-only parameters; its position as the initial "argument" indicates the lack of positional parameters.

Comment: There is a historic reason why it's like this.  In early python a cmp-function was expected.  The possibility to pass a key-function rather than a cmp-function was added at some point.  The possibility to pass the cmp-function was removed in python3.  To make sure old python2-scripts (passing a cmp-function as a positional argument) wouldn't break with an even more obscure error, sort does no longer accept the positional argument.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the documentation for [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), we can see that `key` is a keyword-only argument. So change the line

`birds.sort(lambda b: b.weight())`

to

`birds.sort(key=(lambda b: b.weight()))`

Comment: You don't need the parentheses for the key though.  just `key=lambda b: b.weight()` will suffice.

Comment: @alec935 I beg to differ.  Just take a look at chepner's answer.  So much easier to read without the superfluous parentheses and it does the same thing.  If OP has more code nested before the `sort`, how many closing parentheses is too much?

Answer (score 3):

`sort()` takes a `key` argument and nothing else (well, it can take a `reverse` argument). You supplied `sort()` with an argument it cannot accept. Just add a `key=` before your `lambda`

The error message is because `key` takes keyword arguments, not positional arguments. A positional argument is a name that is not followed by an equal sign and default value.